# How can I convert my SortedSet to a Map with a while loop?

Tags: generics, while-loop, treemap, sortedset

In following method I sort a TreeMap by Value... and now I want to add the entries from the SortedSet to a Map.

```
static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>>
SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K, V> map) {
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> e1, Map.Entry<K, V> e2) {
                    int res = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                    return res != 0 ? res : 1;
                }
            }
    );
    sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
    return sortedEntries;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will do it

```
static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Collection<Map.Entry<K, V>> coll) {
  Map<K, V> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  for (Map.Entry<K, V> e : coll) {
    map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
  }
  return map;
}
```

You can use any map for the variable `map` here. But as you have sorted the entries before, you might want to preserve the ordering. Then `LinkedHashMap` would be a good choice. Maybe you want to express that in the interface and write instead:

```
static <K, V> LinkedHashMap<K, V> toMap(Collection<Map.Entry<K, V>> coll) {
```

Please note that your `Comparator` is not valid. This must be always true, but it is not:

```
comparator.compare(e, e) == 0
```